# Newtonsoft - Serializing and deserializing objects with backing objects and fields

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-7.0

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize this object from my azure redis cache using newtonsoft as my serializer (and fusion cache as a cache helper library). The issue is that when deserializing, the ParentClass reference object in my child class is null so my getter fails. This line (see below)

```
public int Counter {
       get {
         return _counter ?? ParentClass.Counter;
       }
       private set { _counter = value }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this without altering my classes ? I've managed to get it all working by creating private constructors and adding the attribute [JsonConstructor] to them but i'd like to avoid this if possible.

FULL CODE:

Parent class

```
public class ParentClass {
     public string ParentClassId {get; private init;} 
     public string Name {get; private set;}
     public int Counter {get; private set; }

     private readonly List<ChildClass> _childClasses;
     public IReadOnlyCollection<ChildClass> ChildClasses => _childClasses;
  }
```

Child class

```
public class ChildClass {
    public string ParentClassId {get; private init;} 
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    
    public ParentClass ParentClass {get; private set;}
    private int _counter {get; private set;}

    public int Counter {
       get {
         return _counter ?? ParentClass.Counter;
       }
       private set { _counter = value }
    }
}
```

My fusion cache setup:

```
builder.Services.AddFusionCacheNewtonsoftJsonSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings()
 {
     PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
     ContractResolver = new NonPublicContractResolver(),
 });
```

My resolver:

```
public class NonPublicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .Select(p => base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization))
                    .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                               .Where(f => !f.Name.StartsWith("<")) // Exclude compiler-generated fields
                               .Select(f => base.CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization)))
                    .ToList();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.DeclaringType != type)
                continue;

            var pi = type.GetProperty(prop.UnderlyingName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (pi != null)
            {
                prop.Readable = (pi.GetMethod != null);
                prop.Writable = (pi.SetMethod != null);
            }
            else
            {
                var fi = type.GetField(prop.UnderlyingName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (fi != null)
                {
                    prop.Readable = true;
                    prop.Writable = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return props;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, serialization libraries usually require serializable properties to have public getters and setters, and the class to have a public parameterless constructor. To avoid making everything public you could introduce "Data Transfer Objects" (DTOs) that just represent data, without any behavior, that is only used for serialization. This can also simplify version handling if the data changes in the future.